# How to compute styles on <body> or <html> using vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [vuejs style bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to render changes dynamically as the styles are computed.

This works great for everything within the scope of my Vue instance but how can I compute styles for body or html tags?
This used to be possible when you could bind the vue instance to  but vue no longer lets you do it.

I want to dynamically update the background color of  using my computed variables in vue.

edit: added code snippet to demonstrate

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    color: '#666666'
  },
  computed: {
    backgroundColor: function() {
      return {
        'background-color': this.color
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleBackground: function() {
      if(this.color=='#666666'){
        this.color = '#BDBDBD'
      } else {
        this.color = '#666666'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app" :style="backgroundColor">
      <div>
        lots of content...
      </div>
      <button @click="toggleBackground"> Click to toggle </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show us some code :) ?

Comment: added code snippet. If you paste `html {
  background-color: red;
}` in to the css column you can see the issue. The area outside of the vue instance can't be styled by vue

Comment: Why don't you simply remove padding and margin from your html and body tags?

Comment: a lot of browsers allow "overscrolling" effects. It's hard to describe but even if the div is full screen (which I can fix with css) you are still able to see the html/body background colors through scroll bounce-back effects. An example of this is scrolling to the bottom of a page using two fingers on a mac trackpad. The "bounce" effect displays the underlying background color.

Comment: One thing you could do is to make sure that the div you put id="app" on covers the whole viewable page.  Use this div as if it is your body tag of the page.  Everything happens inside of it.  You could then do basically anything you wanted to on that div as if it were just a body tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really need to style `body` itself, you'll need to do it with plain JavaScript in a `watcher`. A simple example is below.

You *should* (not something I've tried, but I'm hypothesizing) be able to defeat overscrolling effects by making body and your outer container non-scrolling. Put a scrollable container inside that. When it overscrolls, it will show your outer container, right?

The reasons for not binding to `body` are [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375#486f) (for React, but applies to Vue).

> What’s the problem with ? Everybody updates it! Some people have
>   non-[Vue] code that attaches modals to it. Google Font Loader will
>   happily put  elements into body for a fraction of second, and
>   your app will break horribly and inexplicably if it tries to update
>   something on the top level during that time. Do you really know what
>   all your third party scripts are doing? What about ads or that social
>   network SDK?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isRed: false
  },
  watch: {
    isRed() {
      document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = this.isRed ? 'red' : null;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="isRed">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include a quick example on a javascript watcher to help others who might have the same question in future?

Comment: I have added a minimal example.

Answer (score 8):

I think I found better solution than using *jQuery/querySelector*

You can add tag style right in your Vue template.
And add v-if on this, smth like that:

```
<style v-if="true">
  body {
    background: green;
  }
</style>
```

Thus you can use computed/methods in this v-if and DOM always will update when you need.

Hope this will help someone ;)

**UPD:**
Using tag "style" in templates is not best idea, but you can create v-style component, then everything will be fine:
*[Use style tags inside vuejs template and update from data model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516424/use-style-tags-inside-vuejs-template-and-update-from-data-model)*

**My snippet:**

```js
Vue.component('v-style', {
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement('style', this.$slots.default)
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isRed: false,
    color: 'yellow',
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="isRed">
  <v-style v-if="isRed">
    body {
      background: red; /*one more benefit - you can write "background: {{color}};" (computed)*/
    }
  </v-style>
</div>
```