# Use style tags inside vuejs template and update from data model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to dynamically update styles `inside` style tags.

However creating a container model for Vue, removes the `style` tags.
I know style tags should belong in the head of the page, but this is just for the sake of ease of use.

So what I would like to have is a wrapper with an element and style tags inside:

```
<div class="setting">
  <style>
    .setting input {
      background: {{bgColor}};
    }
  </style>
  <input class="setting" type="text" v-model="bgColor">
</div>
```

The value from the input should update the value of the css style.
Whenever done with simple div elements this works, but style tags seem to be a problem

The javascript set up is the following:

```
new Vue({
    el: '.setting',
    data: {
      bgColor: 'red'
    }
});
```

However when the style tags have a specific id, this could work, but I can't bind it to an input field.

```
<style id="setting">
  #blue {
    background: {{bg}}
  }
  #blue:hover {
    background: {{bgHover}}
  }
</style>

<div id="blue"></div>
```

and the js:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#setting',
    data: {
      bg: 'blue',
      bgHover: 'red'
    }
});
```

Can someone help me understand how I can achieve updating values between style tags.
[jsfiddle set up](https://jsfiddle.net/1dj54afq/23/)

Thanks.

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/about-using-style-tags-inside-templates/7275/2

Comment: Why do you want to do this instead of data binding to an element's style?

Comment: @zero298 some styles require hover, media queries etc.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here's what I think is a good workaround/solution.

It is just a custom component, so it's as reusable as it gets. All of Vue's goods like `v-if` can all be used.

Another pro is that the styles generated will be there **only as long as the component is**!

```js
Vue.component('v-style', {
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement('style', this.$slots.default)
  }
});


// demo usage, check the template
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bgColor: 'red'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app" class="stuff">
  <v-style>
    .stuff input {
      background: {{bgColor}};
    }
  </v-style>

  Remove "red" and type "yellow":
  <input class="setting" type="text" v-model="bgColor">
</div>
```

The one drawback I see is that since the name of the tag is `<v-style>` (or whatever you chose to call it) and not `<style>`, the IDEs may not color it nicely. But otherwise it'll just be like a regular `<style>` tag.

---

## Standard solution: using `v-bind:style`

This doesn't modify `style` tags, but the standard way of setting styles is using [**object style bindings**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles).

Basically you'd use a `:style` attribute and assign to it the CSS properties of the style in the form of an object. Demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.setting',
  data: {
    bgColor: 'red'
  },
  computed: {
    inputStyles() {
      return {
        background: this.bgColor
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div class="setting">
  Remove "red" and type "yellow":
  <input class="setting" type="text" v-model="bgColor" :style="inputStyles">
</div>
```

Comment: The v-style thing is pretty clever.. great thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 36):

vue-loader (and Vue template compiler [`Vue.compile(..)`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile)) both will filter out any `<style>` tags that are encountered in the `template`.

A simple solution to get around this, is to take advantage of Vue's built-in[`<component>` component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component).

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <component is="style">
      .foo[data-id="{{ uniqueId }}"] {
        color: {{ color }};
      }
      .foo[data-id="{{ uniqueId }}"] .bar {
        text-align: {{ align }}
      }
    </component>
    <div class="foo" :id="id" :data-id="uniqueId">
      <div class="bar">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    uniqueId() {
      // Note: this._uid is not considered SSR safe though, so you
      // may want to use some other ID/UUID generator that will
      // generate the same ID server side and client side. Or just
      // ensure you always provide a unique ID to the `id` prop
      return this.id || this._uid;
    },
    color() {
      return someCondition ? 'red' : '#000';
    },
    align() {
      return someCondition ? 'left' : 'right';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

A unique ID (or some other data-attribute) is required to "scope" the styles to just this component.

This is a nice solution as you can use `v-for` loops to generate the style content if required (which can be reactive to changes in your components data/props/computed props)

```html
<component is="style" type="text/css">
  <template v-for="item in items">
    [data-id="{{ uniqueId }}"] div.bar[data-div-id="item.id"]::before {
      content: "{{ item.content }}";
      color: {{ item.color }};
    }
  </template>
</component>
```

Comment: Nice workaround! I had to use `<component is="'style'">` to prevent VS Code happy

Answer (score 0):

I just created a computed property and used it in the template as v-html

```html
<div v-html="css"></div>
```

```js
computed: {
    css () {
        return `<style>${this.item.css}</style>`
    }
}
```