# How to access content (innerText) of style tag in Vue Component programmatically for entire component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For my current project I need to pass html (and styles) to puppeteer to generate a pdf from it.
I am accessing the html by using `$ref.export.$el.innerHTML` but how can I access the style? My workaround until now was to create a `div` that contains the same style attributes so I can access it as a ref aswell.

It is important to keep the original css syntax to be able to build html out of it afterwars. I also need to get the whole style for the component, not just for single elements.

Comment: Have you tried $ref.export.$el.style ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to access the ref and then you just need to access styles directly or [get computed styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

**template**

```
<!-- vm.$refs.p will be the DOM node -->
<p ref="p">hello</p>
```

Now you could access styles via `this.$refs.p.style`. If you want computed styles you would need helper function as in the example below.

**script**

```
methods: {
  getStylesFromRef() {
    // return this.$refs.p.style if you have style attributes
    // following line for computed styles
    return window.getComputedStyle(this.$refs.p)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question, as I forgot to mention I need all styles not just single element styles

Comment: then you should put styles into a styles block during compile time and access the styles via innerHTML on that block. there is no trivial solution to get all applied styles from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using `<component>` in my template with `is="style"`, that way it is not removed during compile https://stackoverflow.com/a/57331310/8773697