# How to do dynamic pseudo class width calculation inside methods?

Tags: vue.js

I want to build a stepper component (trying to avoid using packages as less as possible). I have created it using plain HTML template and CSS and I want to size the `::before` element according to the `x` number.

Something like this `width: ${100% / 4}`. I tried this method using methods and got a rendering error. Is it possible to do this? Or there is another way to achieve this?

Please have a look at my script:

```html
<template>
  <div class="c-stepper">
    <div class="step-item" :style="drawLinePrecision(4)" v-for="item in 4" :key="item">
      <div class="step-marker">
        <i class="icon icon-duotones-check"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="step-info">
        <p class="step-title">Step 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        drawLinePrecision(length) {
            return `.step-item:not(:last-child)::before {
                content: "";
                height: 3px;
                width: ${(100% / length)};
                position: absolute;
                top: 25%;
                background-color: $primary;
            }`
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import "../../sass/variables";

  .c-stepper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5rem 0rem;
    position: relative;

    .step-item {
      &:not(:last-child)::before {
        content: "";
        height: 3px;
        width: calc(100% / 4);
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        background-color: $primary;
      }
      .step-marker {
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 3px solid $primary;
        border-radius: 50%;

        .icon {
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: it doesn't size precisely when I increase the amount of `step-item`

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516424/use-style-tags-inside-vuejs-template-and-update-from-data-model

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution after some workaround. Instead of doing it like that, I had to make the width of the `.step-item` to be fixed by 100% **except** the last child and move the `position: relative;` from the parent down to the `step-item` itself.

Now, All I need is to set the padding from the parent component which display the `c-stepper` component.

Here is my script:

```html
<template>
  <div class="c-stepper">
    <div class="step-item" v-for="item in 11" :key="item">
      <div class="step-marker">
        <i class="icon icon-duotones-check"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="step-info">
        <p class="step-title">Step 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import "../../sass/variables";

  .c-stepper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5rem 0rem;

    .step-item {
      margin: 0px auto;
      position: relative; // step item must be relative

      &:not(:last-child) {
        width: 100%; // make it fixed
      }

      &:not(:last-child)::before {
        content: "";
        height: 3px;
        width: 100%; // make it 100% width so that it won't let any gap to be rendered in the ui
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        background-color: $primary;
      }
      .step-marker {
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 3px solid $primary;
        border-radius: 50%;

        .icon {
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```