# How to change background in VueJS per user type

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vuejs project.

The "user" level (and public area) has a BG image
The "admin" level has a plain white background.

I read if I use  tags in my template without the scoped keyword it will affect everything, so I tried that, but it didnt produce the desired results.

I tried putting in the parent div, it works almost perfectly, except in logged out page the image doesn't cover whole page, a big white space.

Until recently I had it using css on body in the header component. The CSS below is from my attempt applying it to the parent div

```css
.backgroundCompany{
  background-color: white;
}

.backgroundUser{
  background: url('/img/bg_img.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I tested this: [Stackoverflow #49516424](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516424/use-style-tags-inside-vuejs-template-and-update-from-data-model)
and
[and stackoverflow #48172814](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172814/how-to-compute-styles-on-body-or-html-using-vue-js)

EDITED: attached a partial screenshot of what happens with its in App.vue, as the style for div id=app. Otherwise it works well. Admin gets the pure white background user sees this, but it doesn't cover the whole body.
[image: when in App.vue parent div]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to re-render the component correctly when you change a user. You can add style in a tag in your Vue template. And add :key on this for re-render, smth like that:

```
  <template>
     <div :style="styleObject" :key="uniqKey">
            // your code
     </div>
   </template>

    <script>
        export default {
          data() {
             return {
               styleObject: {
                 backgroundImage: `url(${require('@/assets/path/to/your/img.jpg')})`   
              },
            uniqKey:0 // change this for re-render
          },
          methods: {
            forceRerender() {
              this.styleObject.backgroundImage = '' //new image 
              this.uniqKey+= 1;  
            }
          }
    }       
    </script>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish to change the background image of a component, doing so in the template of that component is simple, you can leverage the class property and dynamically change the class base on the userType(which here I am getting from the props but its up to you how you get the user type value, computed property, store, http call etc....)

```
<template>
  <div :class="userType === 'user' ? 'backgroundUser' : 'backgroundCompany'">
    .....
  </div>
</template>
export default {
  props: {
    userType: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
<style scoped>
  .backgroundCompany{
  background-color: white;
}

.backgroundUser{
  background: url('/img/bg_img.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: No, not the component, I succeeded at doing that, I literally mean the body tag.  My previus test had userHeader and adminHeader component with style tag not scoped.  each had a body{} CSS.

Comment: I can test a similar method, but assigning body{} rther than backgroundUser and backgroundCompany and see how it works.