# How to change body style from vue.obserable store value

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

It is my first time to work with Vue or Web. I have been to working with C to write firmware.

Depends on sidebar state, I would like to change padding-right value of body in App.vue.

whenever button is pushed, isNavOpen value is changed

```
import Vue from "vue";

export const store = Vue.observable({
  isNavOpen: false
});

export const getters = {
  getNavOpen: () => store.isNavOpen
}

export const mutations = {
  setIsNavOpen(yesno) {
    store.isNavOpen = yesno;
  },
  toggleNav() {
    store.isNavOpen = !store.isNavOpen;
  }
};
```

so I would like to change padding-right value of body in App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <div class="logo">my.company</div>
      <Burger></Burger>
    </nav>

    <Sidebar>
      <ul class="sidebar-panel-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </Sidebar>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Burger from "./components/Menu/Burger.vue";
import Sidebar from "./components/Menu/Sidebar.vue";
import { store, getters, mutations } from '@/store.js'


export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    Burger,
    Sidebar
  },
  data:{
      return: {
     isSidebarOpen: this.$getters.getNavOpen()
   }
 }
  
};
</script>

<style>
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 350px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(101, 31, 87);
  background: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(101, 31, 87, 1) 0%,
    rgba(225, 113, 87, 1) 48%,
    rgba(249, 248, 113, 1) 100%
  );
}

</style>
```

I read pages. However it is so hard to combine these codes for me
[change style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172814/how-to-compute-styles-on-body-or-html-using-vue-js)
[vue sidebar tutorial](https://regenrek.com/posts/how-to-create-an-animated-vue-sidebar-menu-with-vue-observable/)

or Is any way to implmement to change padding by sidebar states?

Answer (score 0):

Some thing might be missing in your second block but i assume that you successfully can use true or false value as isSideBarOpen. All you need to do is to use style binding(you can also use class binding but you need to define specific class for padding right) Here is what you need:

```html
<div id="app" :style="(isSideBarOpen) ? 'padding-right: 10px;' : ''">
/* code */
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my second block to get a navopen value by this.$getters.getNavOpen(). but it is not working. even screen is not showed anything. I found that Cannot read property '$getters' of undefined this error

Comment: Where do you manipulate isNavOpen i think in  your <Burger> component you manipulate if  that works correct your problem is using that value inside of #app yeah?